# Promise then is called before the before the previous then was finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I've node app with the following code:

When I run the node app the console.log("after start") is called **before** 
the start was finished, I need it to be **after** the **start** will finished,
what am I doing wrong here?

```
myprocess.start(function() {
  //this is called before the start was finished.
  console.log("After start");
  server.listen(app.get('port'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(' listen to: ' + app.get('port'));
    }

  });
});
```

the file **myprocess.js** contain the following

```
exports.start = function (callback) {

    Validator.validateJson(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

    plugin.parse().then(function (configObj) {
        if (typeof require.cache.persist === 'undefined') {
            require.cache.persist = {};
        }
        require.cache.persist.configObj = configObj;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    var run= function () {
        return Promise.all([
            childPro.create(path.join(value)),
            childPro.findAndUpdateUser()
        ]).spread(function (cmd,updatppEnv) {
            return Promise.all([childProc.executeChildProcess('exec', cmd, updatedAppEnv), Promise.delay(50).then(function (results) {
                return inter.ProcessRun(val);
            })]);
        })
    }();

 //I want that this callback will be called after the run promise will be finished 
 run.then(callback());

}
```

**How can I make the server code runs after all the start process will be finished** ?

UPDATE

For me its sufficient to wait until the `inter.ProcessRun(val)`; is resolved to call to the callback how it can be done?

Comment: Does `childProc.executeChildProcess()` return a promise?  `Promise.all()` can only wait for async operations if you pass it a promise.  It doesn't have any magical powers to know when some async operation is done.  The async operation must return a promise and fulfill that promise when done.  As others have said, `run.then(callback());` should be `run.then(callback);` too so `.then()` can call the callback LATER when ready, not immediately.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks! I dont know when the promise is resolved of the executeChildProcess but I want to execute the callback after the run will be finished...

Comment: @jfriend00 - just to verify for me it is sufficient that  inter.ProcessRun is resolved to proceed with the run to the callback,what should I change then...

Comment: We can't really help you very well when you're using all these functions and we have no idea which return a promise and which don't.  Does `inter.ProcessRun()` return a promise?  Does `childProc.executeChildProcess()` return a promise?

Comment: @jfriend00 - the processRun is resolved but the childProcess sometimes not...

Comment: You're question is hopelessly confusing.  I have no idea what you're actually asking and there just not code for important things included.  And, we've already pointed out some errors.  I doubt this question can proceed any further without a much clearer explanation of the problem and showing us much more code (e.g. all async operations).

Answer (score 3):

You are immediately invoking `callback` by doing `run.then(callback())`. you want `run.then(callback)`.

Comment: Thanks but when I remove the () I dont see the message after start i.e. the server code wasnt called...

Comment: The first console.log not called  console.log("After start"); and the server code either...

Comment: @shopiaT: Well then maybe one of the promises that go into the `Promise.all` is never resolved, or is rejected because of an error?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot a return statement.
Try

```
return run.then(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks I try it but it doesnt help , any other idea?